# Graphics device stops working when clicked

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a question related to RPY2 and the R Graphics

I've just installed python 2.6, R-2.12.2 and rpy2-2.0.8py2.6 for windows Vista 32bits and so far everything seemed to be working pretty well (In Python I can create r vectors, call r objects and the basic stuff)

But them I've tried to plot some graphics and the R Graphics: Device 2 window opens. But when I click on it...it stops responding!

When I try to plot graphics or when I just type `robjects.r.X11()`, even though it opens the R graphics window, it comes empty and it stops working when clicked.

I've googled this issue but couldn't find much information.

I've also tried to get older versions of rpy2, rpy, python, R and install all of them..but in any combination I just got the same issue!!